# Let $G=(\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{1\},*)$, where $*: x+y-xy$, and $H=\{0,\pm 2,\pm 4,...\}$. Show that $H\le G$.

Tags: group-theory

I am having trouble checking algebraically if one group $H$ is a subgroup of the other group $G$. In an abstract way I can do it (I show that it says closing, neutral and inverse element), but when the example is algebraic I get confused, can you help me?

My question: $G = (\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{1\},*)$, where $*: x+y-xy$, and $H=\{0,\pm 2,\pm 4,...\}$. Show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format the mathematical formulas in your MSE questions.Also what does "$\ldots$" mean in $\{\pm 4, \pm 2, 0, \ldots\}$ - there is no obvious pattern there?

Comment: You can handle it in a slightly more abstract way if you realize that

$$H = \left\{ x \in \Bbb Z \; \middle| \; x = 2k \text{ for a } k \in \Bbb Z \right\}$$

(at least based on what I assume is intended: the even integers, i.e. $H = 2 \Bbb Z$)

Comment: Reordered definition $H$ to make more sense. .... One thing you need to show (and it's fairly obvious here) is that every member of $H$ is in $G$. After that you just need to show that $H$ is a group (and that $G$ is a group, if that isn't obvious).

Comment: I think $\Bbb{Q}-1$ in the question is supposed to mean $\Bbb{Q}\setminus\{1\}$ which is, I think, a group under this operation. I think $G$ is just the multiplicative group of $\Bbb{Q}$ viewed under a rational linear transformation that swaps $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false.  The group identity under this operation is $0$, but $4$ has no inverse in $H$:  $4+y-4y=0 \Rightarrow 4=3y \Rightarrow y = \frac 43 \notin H$.  I suspect that $H$ is supposed to be $ \{ r \in \Bbb Q \setminus \{ 1 \} \mid r = \frac{2n}{k}, k, n \in \Bbb Z, k \text{ odd} \}.$